# Вывести данные пользовательских полей в графическом виде для товара WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

В карточке товара WooCommerce нужно вывести поля с разной степенью вкуса кофе - "горчинка", "насыщенность" и пр., как на примере ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю, на странице редактирования товара создаются пользовательские поля, где нужно указать цифры от 1 до 10 и потом вывести их в графическом виде.

Но я никак не могу найти подходящее решение. Даже в плагинах с дополнительными полями для товаров, ничего подобного нет.

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать. Может у кого-нибудь были похожие задачи.

Comment: и в чем проблема? добавь инпут с типом число забей ему максимальное возможное значение, выведи его значение на фронте через цикл для отрисовки степени вкуса

Answer (score -1):

> Но я никак не могу найти подходящее решение.

Для этого существуют [произвольные поля](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F).  В качестве значения задаётся допустимый диапазон (1..10) и делается стилизация.